# How to optimize the strucuture of 'bookings' in a booking app?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I have asked a few questions about working with arrays in Firestore and was recently pointed out to the fact that arrays have a size limit and another structure should be used instead.

I am currently adding bookings to a 'bookings' array. Each booking is an object with about 10 key-value pairs. I plan to have as many as 400 of those per day (e.g. 16-06-2020, see image below), and I was wondering if using arrays would still be OK or if it could be a problem due to array size limit.

If this could potentially be a problem, is there a better structure that would optimize this? This structure would preferably:

1. have no problems with limits of 'bookings'
2. be easy to add to and remove from
3. be easy to modify each booking. e.g. modify a property in an object.

Here is a screenshot of what my current structure looks like:

[image]

I have googled quite a lot but couldn't really find a consensus on how to structure this given my 3 preferences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays are not fundamentally limited in size.   The size limit you'll run into is [1MB for the *entire document*](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#collections_documents_and_fields).

If your document data is not strictly bounded to 1MB, then you should consider moving nested data to a subcollection.  So, instead of this:

```
approvedBusinesses (collection)
  - {id} (document)
    - bookings (nested objects)
```

use this:

```
approvedBusinesses (collection)
  - {id} (document)
    - bookings (collection)
      - dd-mm-yyyy (document)
```

It's up to you to determine what best meets your specific needs.  The point is to move unbounded data into documents in subcollections where the size of the document will be guaranteed 1MB or less.

Comment: Currently, as I retrieve a 'approvedBusinesses' document, all of the 'bookings' of that particular business are also retrieved. Does your suggestion to use subcollections prevent that? Meaning, if I retrieve a document from approvedBusiness, it'll not get its subcollections unless I specify so?

Comment: No. Firebase queries are shallow and don't consider subcollections.  Getting documents from a subcollection requires another query.

Comment: You mentioned using ```dd-mm-yyyy (document)``` and I Iike the idea. Now, what would be the optimal way to add each individual 'booking' to this 'date' document? Pass them as an object? Pass them as an object to an array? I'm puzzled by how to do this to a single document. I'd love to now what solution an experienced developer would come up with (with my points 2 and 3 in mind above). Googled but couldn't find many examples... I've only been working with Firestore and dbs for 2 months.

Comment: I don't really have an opinion about how to structure your code.  If you are trying something, and it doesn't work the way you expect, please post a new question entirely.